# How to set X-FRAMES_OPTIONS to any other value than deny for Django media files embedding purposes?

Tags: python, django

I am developing a procedure where an already uploaded/generated file gets displayed in the user's dashboard through embed/iframe HTML tags. These files are HTML divs generated by plotly (Python, server-side generated).

So when I try to view these files through iframe like this:

```
      <iframe
          width="100%"
          height="100%"
          frameBorder="0"
          src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/plots/20/plot-x-a-1.html"
        />
```

I get the following error through developers tools:
`Refused to display 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.`

As you are aware that usually it is solved by either disabling the XFramesOptions middleware entirely or to set it as `ALLOWALL`.

The issue is, neither disabling this middleware nor adding these lines:

```
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'ALLOWALL'
XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_METHODS = ['POST','GET','OPTIONS', 'PUT', 'DELETE']
```

helped prevent the error. My guess is, media stream requires x_frames_options to be set to `AllowAll` or `sameorigin` but there is no documentation about how to do that.

Is my reasoning correct? why would the browser still reject my iframe requests after such changes?

Note: development is totally local at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation on [**`Clickjacking Protection`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/clickjacking/#how-to-use-it) you should set the value of `X_FRAME_OPTIONS` in your `settings.py` to:

```
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
```

And also ensure that the `XFrameOptionsMiddleware` is enabled:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

Comment: In my case i had <a href="#"></a> request going from iframe to server. By removing it solved the issue :)